# Access VBA SQL statement received syntax error when attempting to INSERT values

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, insert, iif

I'm using Access VBA to insert values into a table based on information from a form. The SQL statement is throwing a syntax error, however, if I pull the SQL into the query builder it will run so I'm not sure where the syntax error is.

```
INSERT INTO [TBLactionstaken] (RecordNumber, ActionID, ReasonID, ActionBy, LetterTo, LetterAddress, LetterType, MANHType, MANReqAmt, NRReason1, NRReason2, NRReason3, NRReason4, NRReason5, RFActionID, ActionDate, ActionStatus) 

Values (" & Forms![frmActions]![txtrecordNumber2] & ", " & Forms![frmActions]![lstActions] & ", " & Forms![frmActions]![lstReasons] & ", '" & _
    Forms![frmActions]![txtActionBy] & "', '" & apostrophe(Forms![frmActions]![cboLetterTo]) & "', '" & Forms![frmActions]![cboLetterAddress] & "', '" & _
    Forms![frmActions]![cboLetterType] & "', '" & IIf(IsNull(Forms![frmActions]![cboMANHType]), "", Forms![frmActions]![cboMANHType]) & "', " & _
    Forms![frmActions]![cboReqAmt] & ", " & IIf(IsNull(Forms![frmActions]![cboNRReason1]), "", "'" & Forms![frmActions]![cboNRReason1] & "'") & ", " & _
    IIf(IsNull(Forms![frmActions]![cboNRReason2]), "", "'" & Forms![frmActions]![cboNRReason2] & "'") & ", " & _
    IIf(IsNull(Forms![frmActions]![cboNRReason3]), "", "'" & Forms![frmActions]![cboNRReason3] & "'") & ", " & _
    IIf(IsNull(Forms![frmActions]![cboNRReason4]), "", "'" & Forms![frmActions]![cboNRReason4] & "'") & ", " & _
    IIf(IsNull(Forms![frmActions]![cboNRReason5]), "", "'" & Forms![frmActions]![cboNRReason5] & "'") & ", " & _
    IIf(IsNull(Forms![frmActions]![cboActID]), "", "'" & Forms![frmActions]![cboActID] & "'") & ", #" & Forms![frmActions]![txtDatereceived] & "#, 'Pending')"
```

Comment: What happens if you comment al except one field and go from there ? So 1 value and 1 select etc...

Comment: @MathiasZ I tried going line by line. I can get through all of them up to cboReqAmt and start getting the syntax errors.  This is the output: INSERT INTO [TBLactionstaken] (RecordNumber, ActionID, ReasonID, ActionBy, LetterTo, LetterAddress, LetterType, MANHType, MANReqAmt, NRReason1, NRReason2, NRReason3, NRReason4, NRReason5, RFActionID, ActionDate, ActionStatus) Values (123456, 2, 22, 'Associate', 'Participant', 'Right', 'Batch Initial', 'Medical', , '', '', '', '', '', '', #2/7/2024#, 'Pending')

Comment: I don't see your rude comments on any other feeds. You don't like it don't read it.

Comment: Sorry if I offended you, that wasn't my intention, but which part of my comment was rude? The unreadable script or my suggestion to use parameters?

Comment: I accept you apology, please be aware of how things may come across to others. I apologize I don't know what you mean by parameters. I'm newer to posting questions.

Comment: See a simple example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60450981/access-add-new-sql-data/60451210#60451210 and a more comprehensive one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509615/how-do-i-use-parameters-in-vba-in-the-different-contexts-in-microsoft-access

Comment: Keep in mind, there's an option to define the parameters in the query editor; just type the name and select the data type from the drop-down. Then just assign the values in VBA and execute the query.

Comment: Could you try replacing the Forms![frmActions]![cboReqAmt] with the nr 0. Does it insert then ? It looks like you pass nothing between these parameters  'Medical', , '',

Comment: Ah, but aren't SQL strings faster? This DB wasn't built by me I inherited it so this is something that was this way and wasn't working. I'm reluctant to change it in fear that 10 others things may break. LOL I will try it. Thank you!

Comment: @MathiasZ that didn't work either. The point is to pass nothing into those fields bc the user input boxes from the form are blank.

Comment: Would be helpful to show the surrounding VBA for context, as well as (eg) the `apostrophe` method.  Also -you could shorten that whole thing by assigning `Forms![frmActions]` to a variable like `f`...

Comment: I never allow empty strings in textfields. Can't pass NULL with text or date delimiters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of code is simply not maintainable. As you have (probably painfully) seen when trying to debug it.

I would replace it with `RecordSet.AddNew`, where you assign form values to recordset values line by line. This is readable and maintainable.
See comments.

```
Sub DoSave()

    Dim rs As Dao.Recordset
    Dim f As Access.Form
    
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TBLactionstaken", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)
    Set f = Forms![frmActions]
    
    With rs
        .AddNew
        !RecordNumber = f!txtrecordNumber2
        !ActionID = f!lstActions
        !ReasonID = f!lstReasons
        !ActionBy = f!txtActionBy
        ' no need to check for apostrophes in strings...
        !LetterTo = f!cboLetterTo
        
        ' etc etc
        
        ' no special handling of NULL values necessary...
        !NRReason1 = f!cboNRReason1
        ' ... unless your table does actually want empty strings instead of NULLs, then do:
        !NRReason2 = Nz(f!cboNRReason2, "")

        ' you could also do...
        For i = 1 To 5
            rs("NRReason" & i) = f("cboNRReason" & i)
        Next i
        
        ' etc etc
        
        .Update
        .Close
    End With
    
End Sub
```