# Facing an error in MS Access while getting the data From from to insert it into the table

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am getting this error

> Runtime error 3134

while clicking on the button in form to insert the data into table from the form.

Here's the code that I was trying to execute.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Main Sheet(Student Name, Pick Up Time, Home Address, Home City, School Hours, School Name, School Address, School City, Notes, School District, Parent Tel, Emergency Contact, Driver)" & _
    "VALUES(" & Me.stdName & "','" & Me.pickUpTime & "','" & Me.homeAddress & "','" & Me.homeCity & "','" & Me.schoolHours & "','" & Me.schoolName & "','" & Me.schoolAddress & "','" & Me.schoolCity & "','" & Me.notes & "','" & Me.schoolDistrict & "','" & Me.parentTel & "','" & Me.emergencyContact & "','" & Me.driver & "')"
    'refresh data in list on form
    MainForm.Form.Requery
```

Comment: This seems to be just a generic error for syntax. Looks like you are at the very least missing a single quote here: "VALUES(" & Me.stdName  . Possibly, or probably other things too. The best thing to do is prepare the query as a string and debug.print to see the actual constructed query. Debugging otherwise is just really hard on the eyes.

Comment: Use the Access query designer to build a `SELECT` query which fetches those target fields from your table.  Then switch the query from *Design View* to *SQL View* to see how Access SQL handles object names which includes spaces.

Comment: And particular reason why you don't just use a bound form, and thus the data save is automatic and occurs without having to write code.

Comment: Will error if pass Null to text or date fields. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77955868/access-vba-sql-statement-received-syntax-error-when-attempting-to-insert-values

Answer (score 0):

You need brackets for table and field names with spaces and properly formatted string expressions for numeric and date fields:

```vb
Dim Sql As String

Sql = "INSERT INTO [Main Sheet] ([Student Name], [Pick Up Time], [Home Address], [Home City], [School Hours], [School Name], [School Address], [School City], Notes, [School District], [Parent Tel], [Emergency Contact], Driver) " & _
"VALUES ('" & Me.stdName & "',#" & Format(Me.pickUpTime, "hh\:nn" & "#,'" & Me.homeAddress & "','" & Me.homeCity & "','" & Me.schoolHours & "','" & Me.schoolName & "','" & Me.schoolAddress & "','" & Me.schoolCity & "','" & Me.notes & "','" & Me.schoolDistrict & "','" & Me.parentTel & "','" & Me.emergencyContact & "','" & Me.driver & "')"

CurrentDb.Execute Sql
```